# Retrieving ContentType from SPListItem is NULL

Tags: content-type, splistitem

I am trying to get the ContentType.Name of the Event (SPListItem)  however it is NULL when I try to access it.  I'm getting a value for the ContentTypeID, so I would assume that I would be able to access the ContentType name.

[image: ContentType Null]

Here is a general outline of my code, using a CAML query to access the list, then looping through

```
        using (SPWeb EventsSite = SPContext.Current.Site.OpenWeb(eventSiteURL.TrimEnd('/')))
        {
            SPList EventsList = EventsSite.GetList(EventsSite.ServerRelativeUrl.TrimEnd('/') + "/Lists/Events");
            SPQuery EventQuery = new SPQuery();
            EventQuery.ViewFields = @"<FieldRef Name='Event_x0020_Description' /><FieldRef Name='Event_x0020_Name' /><FieldRef Name='EventStartDate' /><FieldRef Name='EventEndDate' />
                                      <FieldRef Name='Event_x0020_Tuition' /><FieldRef Name='EventMeals' /><FieldRef Name='EventCancellation' /><FieldRef Name='EventSeats' />;
            EventQuery.Query = string.Format(@"<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Associated_x0020_Site' /><Value Type='Text'>{0}</Value></Eq></Where>", SPContext.Current.Web.ID);
            Event = EventsList.GetItems(EventQuery)[0];
        }

// Event.ContentType.Name is NULL ?
var MyEventName = Event.ContentType.Name;
```

Comment: What is the event type? ItemAdded or ItemAdding?

Comment: Can you try checking `SPListItem["ContentType"]` as a field value?

Comment: Thanks Arsalan, SPListItem["ContentType"] worked I had the incorrect syntax when I had tried that previously.

Answer (score 1):

If you add "ContentType" to the ViewFields, you can access the name of the content type with the indexer of the SPListItem:

```
SPListItem item = ...;
string contentTypeName = item["ContentType"] as string;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you specify ViewFields in a query, you will get values only for the selected fields in your result. Try to remove ViewFields from your query.

Comment: I tried adding <FieldRef Name='ContentType' /> to my ViewFields but didn't get any results.  Should that work to return the ContentType object?

Comment: No. I think it doesn't work, because it's not an item field value. If you don't want to get the all SPListItem object, you can try to get SPContentType from the list by the GUID, like this: 'var ct = EventsList.ContentTypes[Event.ContentTypeId]', and then you can get the name like ct.Name

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I looked through all of the ID's in the EventsList.ContentTypes and the Event.ContentTypeId doesn't exsist in there?  I currently have 6 content types that show up in my ContentTypes collection, but non of the ID's match the ContentTypeId, any idea why these would not match?

Answer (score 0):

You can find `SPContentType` using the ID value as below

```
SPContentTypeId CTypeId = new SPContentTypeId(Event["ContentTypeId"]);
SPContentType CType = web.AvailableContentTypes[CTypeId];
```

Now use

```
CType.Name
```